# Mouse hover not working on overlapped elements

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-plugins

In the following pie chart plugin, the tool-tip title are not showing for some of the elements.

http://jsfiddle.net/QzWrL/5/

```
$.widget("ui.piechart", {
    options: {
        width: 400,
        height: 200,
        data: null,
        labels: null,
        legendcolorwidth: '20px',
        legendwidth: '200px'
    },

    _create: function () {
        var pierIndex = 0;
        var labelIndex = 0;
        var colorIndex = 0;

        var width = this.options.width;
        var height = width / 2;        
        function getPier(deg, label, sno) {            
            var cssSize = "width:" + height + "px;height:" + height + "px;";
            var halfSize = height * .5;
            var commonCss = "position:absolute;clip : rect(" +
           halfSize + "px," +
           height + "px," + height + "px,0px);";
            var html =
           $("<div style='-moz-transform: rotate(" +
           pierIndex + "deg);-webkit-transform: rotate(" +
           pierIndex + "deg);-ms-transform:rotate(" +
           pierIndex + "deg);" + cssSize + commonCss +
             "' ><span class='piedata' id='piedata" + sno + "' href='#' class='pier' style='cursor:pointer;-moz-transform:rotate(" +
           (deg - 180) + "deg);-webkit-transform:rotate(" +
           (deg - 180) + "deg);-ms-transform:rotate(" +
           (deg - 180) + "deg);" + cssSize + commonCss + "border-radius:" +
           height + "px;box-shadow : inset 0 0 8px gray;background:" +
           colors[(colorIndex++ % colors.length)] +
           "' title='" + label + " (" + Math.round(deg / 3.6) + "%)' ></span></div>");
            pierIndex += deg;
            return html;
        }

        this.element.css('width', width / 2 + 'px')
        .css('height', height + 'px')
        .toggleClass('ui-piechart-default');
        var total = 0;
        if (this.options.labels == null)
            this.options.labels = new Array();
        for (var i = 0; i < this.options.data.length; i++) {
            if (this.options.labels[i] == undefined)
                this.options.labels[i] = "";
            total += this.options.data[i];
            totalchartarea += this.options.data[i];
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < this.options.data.length; i++)
            this.element.append(getPier((360 / total) * this.options.data[i], this.options.labels[i], i));

        this._createLabels();
    },

    _createLabels: function () {
        var left = this.options.width * 0.6;
        var rows = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < this.options.data.length; i++) {
            rows += "<tr class='piedatalegend'  id='piedatalegend" + i + "' style='cursor:pointer' ><td style='background-color: " +
            colors[i % colors.length] + ";min-width: " + this.options.legendcolorwidth + ";min-height:" + this.options.legendcolorwidth + ";'></td><td>&nbsp;" +
                this.options.labels[i] +
            "</td></tr>";
        }

        this.element.append("<div class='ui-piechart-legend'  style='height:" + this.options.width / 2 + "px;overflow-y: auto;width:" + this.options.legendwidth + ";position:relative;left: " +
          left + "px;'><table style='border-spacing: 0px;background: white;padding: 4px;'>" +

          rows +

          "</table></div>");
    }
});
```

Check the labels from a to e they wont show tooltip. It's because the elements are overlapped and drawn. Even if I set z-index in any order the tool-tip is not showing.

Is there anyway I can overcome this mouseover issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `div`s will always overlap each other, because their rotation points (`transform-origin`) are positioned to center. Try to modify it eg. top left:

http://jsfiddle.net/Stocki/DtC4B/

I hope this `CSS` + `HTML` 'demo' can help you. If you have any question please write a comment. :)

#### Edit:

**The working version with JS: http://jsfiddle.net/Stocki/DtC4B/6/**

Comment: I cant sacrifice the Jquery plugin concept :). because in my project i have to draw a pie chart based on the array of objects retrieved from DB.

Comment: I modified my code with your JS; not yet perfect, but I have to go home (There's 17:14 here). =) http://jsfiddle.net/Stocki/DtC4B/3/ Tomorrow can I check it out perfectly.

Comment: Thanks . that seems like working :) http://jsfiddle.net/DtC4B/4/ What did you mean not yet perfect??? But if the width is above 450, i can see some div elevated in background. are you saying that???? http://jsfiddle.net/DtC4B/5/

Comment: Well, nothing but small things. (Box-shadow, width/height). I am glad to be working. **Edit**: Yes, `background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);` is unnecessary in `#chart`.

Comment: If your method is working, please modify your answer. so that i can test n vote it.

Comment: Oh, I found a bug: http://jsfiddle.net/DtC4B/4/ the `c` part is overlapped (z-index problem), 10 mins and I fix it.

Comment: It wasn't easy, but now it is _perfect_. :)

Comment: +1 for your kind help and effort. lemme check it with mine. there still some issue of pie being cut of when height is increased. I will try and fix that.

Answer (score 0):

```
onmouseout='_resetHighlights()'
```

function `_resetHighlights()` is undifined!

```
onmouseover='_identifyobject(" + i + ");'
```

function `_identifyobject()` is undifined!

Comment: Those are my predefined functions available in another JS file, which has nothing to do with the issue. Have updated the fiddle and code now.

Answer (score 0):

You have a really decent algorithm that calculates the area each element should occupy in the pie chart.  I would append the mouse over event to the parent element of all the pie slices and and use the mouse position to figure out which slice I'm above.  Just due to the overlap of element, the DOM is going to have a hard time deducing which element is the target of the mouseover event.  Again, you have a really good algorithm for calculating these areas so I'm sure you could utilize that somehow to figure this out.  Does that make sense?  I hope so!